# How can i add missing month value and remove duplicate in dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have a dataset that looks like this :

| vaR | date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2022 |
| A | 1/2/2022 |
| A | 1/3/2022 |
| B | 1/1/2022 |
| B | 1/3/2022 |
| C | 1/1/2022 |
| C | 1/1/2022 |
| C | 1/2/2022 |
| C | 1/2/2022 |
| C | 1/3/2022 |

And i want to be arranged by month and by the var variable. But if a month is not recorded (missing) i want to be added (to be appeared ) in the new column named Month and to mutate (dplyr phrase) another column that will check if there was an entry on that month (logical condition).But there are some entries for example C that has more that one entries which counts for one (distinct).

Ideally is must look like this :

| var | Quarter | Month | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | TRUE |
| A | 1 | 2 | TRUE |
| A | 1 | 3 | TRUE |
| B | 1 | 1 | TRUE |
| B | 1 | 2 | FALSE |
| B | 1 | 3 | TRUE |
| C | 1 | 1 | TRUE |
| C | 1 | 2 | TRUE |
| C | 1 | 3 | TRUE |

As a start i have tried this one in R :

```
var = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",2),rep("C",5));var
date = c(as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"),
         as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"),
         as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"))
data = tibble(var,date)
quarter = 1
data%>%
  dplyr::mutate(month = lubridate::month(date),
                Quarter = quarter)
```

But i don't know how to add the missing month and check for the verified condition.
Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `complete()` to fill in the missing months and then check whether they have an associated date, then use `distinct()` to find the unique combinations.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

var = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",2),rep("C",5))
date = c(as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"),
         as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"),
         as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"))
data = tibble(var,date)
quarter = 1
data %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(date)) %>% 
  complete(var, month) %>% 
  mutate(Quarter = quarter,
         Condition = !is.na(date)) %>% 
  distinct(var, month, Quarter, Condition)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   var   month Quarter Condition
#>   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>    
#> 1 A         1       1 TRUE     
#> 2 A         2       1 TRUE     
#> 3 A         3       1 TRUE     
#> 4 B         1       1 TRUE     
#> 5 B         2       1 FALSE    
#> 6 B         3       1 TRUE     
#> 7 C         1       1 TRUE     
#> 8 C         2       1 TRUE     
#> 9 C         3       1 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Why are you hard coding quarter?

Comment: Only because the OP did... @HomerJaySimpson you can use `Quarter = lubridate::quarter(month)` to avoid hardcoding it.

Comment: thanks for your answer @lhs I made a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72467405/how-can-i-keep-additional-variables-after-grouping-in-some-other-variables-in-dp) according to your answer.Plz have a look if you can help.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach it this way:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
libraty(tidyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(month=month(date),quarter=quarter(month))
left_join(
  expand(df, var,month,quarter),
  select(df,var, month) %>% mutate(condition=TRUE) %>%  distinct()
) %>% mutate(condition=!is.na(condition))
```

Output

```
  var   month quarter condition
  <chr> <dbl>   <int> <lgl>    
1 A         1       1 TRUE     
2 A         2       1 TRUE     
3 A         3       1 TRUE     
4 B         1       1 TRUE     
5 B         2       1 FALSE    
6 B         3       1 TRUE     
7 C         1       1 TRUE     
8 C         2       1 TRUE     
9 C         3       1 TRUE
```