# How can I keep additional variables after grouping in some other variables in dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Previously today I posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72461943/how-can-i-add-missing-month-value-and-remove-duplicate-in-dplyr-in-r/72462277#72462277) but I have an additional question that has been raised.

If I had to more variables in original data frame (loc, height):

```
var = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",2),rep("C",5));var
date = c(as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"),
         as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"),
         as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"))
loc = c(rep("london",3),rep("berlin",2),rep("cairo",5))
height =c(13,14,15,13,15,16,12,14,13,15)
data = tibble(var,date,loc,height);data
```

how can I keep the corresponding values of the loc variable and the total (sum) of height in each month (in addition in the previously answered question) ?

Ideally it must look now like this :

| var | Quarter | Month | Condition | loc | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | TRUE | London | 13 |
| A | 1 | 2 | TRUE | London | 14 |
| A | 1 | 3 | TRUE | London | 15 |
| B | 1 | 1 | TRUE | berlin | 13 |
| B | 1 | 2 | FALSE | berlin | 0 |
| B | 1 | 3 | TRUE | berlin | 15 |
| C | 1 | 1 | TRUE | cairo | 28 |
| C | 1 | 2 | TRUE | cairo | 27 |
| C | 1 | 3 | TRUE | cairo | 15 |

any help ? how I do it in R using dplyr ?

Comment: Why is the output `height` value changes when compared to your input

Comment: The `height` calculation is not clear (by group).  Otherwise, you can use `.keep_all` in `distinct` i.e. `data %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(date)) %>% 
  complete(var, month) %>% 
  mutate(Quarter = quarter,
         Condition = !is.na(date)) %>% 
  distinct(var, month, Quarter, Condition, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% fill(loc) %>% select(-date)`

Comment: they are summarized by group month if I have understood your question.

Comment: I tried by month, but it wouldn't give the value in the expected output `data %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(date)) %>% 
  complete(var, month) %>% 
  mutate(Quarter = quarter,
         Condition = !is.na(date)) %>% 
  distinct(var, month, Quarter, Condition, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% fill(loc) %>% select(-date) %>% group_by(month) %>% mutate(height = sum(height, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% ungroup`

Comment: is the sum of each month.If you group_by month before the complete pipe line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the previous solution, add `.keep_all = TRUE` in `distinct` and then `fill` the `loc` column with the previous non-NA value

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>%   
   mutate(month = lubridate::month(date)) %>%
   group_by(var, month) %>% 
   mutate(height = sum(height)) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   complete(var, month, fill = list(height = 0)) %>% 
   mutate(Quarter = quarter, Condition = !is.na(date)) %>% 
   distinct(var, month, Quarter, Condition, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
   fill(loc) %>% 
   select(-date)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 6
  var   month loc    height Quarter Condition
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>    
1 A         1 london     13       1 TRUE     
2 A         2 london     14       1 TRUE     
3 A         3 london     15       1 TRUE     
4 B         1 berlin     13       1 TRUE     
5 B         2 berlin      0       1 FALSE    
6 B         3 berlin     15       1 TRUE     
7 C         1 cairo      28       1 TRUE     
8 C         2 cairo      27       1 TRUE     
9 C         3 cairo      15       1 TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on previous answer:

```
data <- data %>% mutate(month=month(date),quarter=quarter(month))

left_join(
  expand(data, var,month,quarter),
  data %>% group_by(var,month, date,loc) %>% 
    summarize(height=sum(height), .groups="drop") %>%
    select(-date) %>% 
    mutate(condition=TRUE) 
) %>% 
  mutate(condition=!is.na(condition),height=if_else(is.na(height),0,height)) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% fill(loc)
```

Output:

```
  var   month quarter loc    height condition
  <chr> <dbl>   <int> <chr>   <dbl> <lgl>    
1 A         1       1 london     13 TRUE     
2 A         2       1 london     14 TRUE     
3 A         3       1 london     15 TRUE     
4 B         1       1 berlin     13 TRUE     
5 B         2       1 berlin      0 FALSE    
6 B         3       1 berlin     15 TRUE     
7 C         1       1 cairo      28 TRUE     
8 C         2       1 cairo      27 TRUE     
9 C         3       1 cairo      15 TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is `dplyr` solution: This part `complete(var,Month,  fill = list(height = 0))` is from @akrun:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(var, Quarter = quarter(date), Month = month(date), loc) %>% 
  summarise(height = sum(height)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  complete(var,Month,  fill = list(height = 0)) %>% 
  fill(c(Quarter, loc), .direction = "down") %>% 
  mutate(Condition = ifelse(height ==  0 , FALSE, TRUE))
```

```
  var   Month Quarter loc    height Condition
  <chr> <dbl>   <int> <chr>   <dbl> <lgl>    
1 A         1       1 london     13 TRUE     
2 A         2       1 london     14 TRUE     
3 A         3       1 london     15 TRUE     
4 B         1       1 berlin     13 TRUE     
5 B         2       1 berlin      0 FALSE    
6 B         3       1 berlin     15 TRUE     
7 C         1       1 cairo      28 TRUE     
8 C         2       1 cairo      27 TRUE     
9 C         3       1 cairo      15 TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nesting()` within the `complete()` step to get only the combinations you want, and then group by everything you want to keep distinct before summing the heights:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
var = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",2),rep("C",5));var
date = c(as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"),
         as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"),
         as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/01/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/02/01"),as.Date("2022/03/01"))
loc = c(rep("london",3),rep("berlin",2),rep("cairo",5))
height =c(13,14,15,13,15,16,12,14,13,15)
data = tibble(var,date,loc,height)

data %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(date)) %>% 
  complete(month, nesting(var, loc)) %>% 
  mutate(Quarter = lubridate::quarter(month),
         Condition = !is.na(date)) %>% 
  group_by(across(-c(height, date))) %>% 
  summarise(height = sum(height), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  arrange(var)

#> # A tibble: 9 × 6
#>   month var   loc    Quarter Condition height
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <int> <lgl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1 A     london       1 TRUE          13
#> 2     2 A     london       1 TRUE          14
#> 3     3 A     london       1 TRUE          15
#> 4     1 B     berlin       1 TRUE          13
#> 5     2 B     berlin       1 FALSE         NA
#> 6     3 B     berlin       1 TRUE          15
#> 7     1 C     cairo        1 TRUE          28
#> 8     2 C     cairo        1 TRUE          27
#> 9     3 C     cairo        1 TRUE          15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>